# How to program (compile/write) a firmware of DSPGroup's baseband chip DE56

Tags: firmware

There are several DECT cordless phones around me not only in my home, but also in my company.

All of them have a same brand.

Through the googling I found the fact that the DECT is very weak in security, so I decided to modify the firmware of my cordless phone first, then other phones too.

I have tried to see the phone's structure.
The phone was mainly consisted in two parts: baseband chip (DE562xxxx) and RF transceiver (RF19Z).

But I don't know how can I program it, especially DE56 baseband chip.

I only want to modify (encrypt/decrypt) the voice data after compressed and/or before decompressed.

Who can help me? Please inform me how to do it, what is necessary. I'm familiar with ASM, C and C++.